# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Where's my Worklight Console gone?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-console

I've just upgraded to Worklight 6.0 and now, I can't find my console! I used to visit http:// localhost:8080/console but I can't get there now.

Worklight tells me the following:

> ```
> [AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http:// IBM-VPFetc:10080
> [AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application _MobileBrowserSimulator started in 1.121 seconds.
> [AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http:// IBM-VPFetc:10080/
> ```

I can get to the Mobile Simulator, but it's just blank. The other link loads nothing. How do I see my console view?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please read the [updated IBM Worklight Information Center](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp) to familiarize yourself with changes done in Worklight 6.0

Worklight 6.0 is now based on Liberty. Consequently, just as you would when using an external application server, in order to now reach the Worklight Console you must also specify the context root in the URL:

```
http://myHost:port/contextRoot/console
```

The context root by default is the name of your project. 
For example:

```
http://localhost:10080/WorklightStarter/console
```

Alternatively you can also right-click on your project and choose `Open Worklight Console` from the context menu.

Note: In Worklight 6.0 the port number has changed from `8080` to `10080`.

Answer (score 1):

And the port number has changed from 8080 in Worklight 5.0.6 to 10080 in Worklight v6.0 as seen in the post above